# How to configure multiple django project running on different system ports using same IP with gunicorn

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

This question is a bit lengthy, but I tried to provide as much information as possible from my doubts and trials. I've been fiddling with gunicorn and nginx configurations to host 3 django projects on an AWS EC2 ubuntu server. I've been unable to sort them to run, neither been able to fully understand the settings.

**(1)** First of all I have them them as follows (Each project folder has its own venv setup):

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 26 02:10 first_project/
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 26 01:20 second_project/
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 26 01:25 third_project/
```

**(2)** I tried creating separate .socket files in `/etc/systemd/system/` folder

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Mar 26 02:17  gunicorn_first.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Mar 26 02:19  gunicorn_second.socket
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Mar 26 02:22  gunicorn_third.socket
```

**(3)** and included all of them with same content:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**(4)** Post adding .socket files, I added .service files

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Mar 26 02:35  gunicorn_first.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Mar 26 02:39  gunicorn_second.service
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  112 Mar 26 02:44  gunicorn_third.service
```

**(5)** and added content as follows **(NTH  -> first , second, third)**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn_NTH.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/NTH_project
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/NTH_project/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --access-logfile - --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock NTH_project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**(6)** And finally my nginx default configuration `(/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default)` as follows. I've opened ports 8081, 8082, 8083 - one for each project

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name MY_IP;

    location /first_project {
        root /home/ubuntu/first_project;
    }
    
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_first.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8082;
    server_name MY_IP;

    location /second_project {
        root /home/ubuntu/second_project;
    }
    
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_second.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 8083;
    server_name MY_IP;

    location /third_project {
        root /home/ubuntu/third_project;
    }
    
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_third.sock;
    }
}
```

The above approach doesn't work, so I replaced proxy_pass in each with `http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock` -> and if I do so, only the last application (8083) is working, when I send requests to endpoint from postman `(http://MY_IP:8083/some_endpoint)`. The other 2 are stating django error that the route is not found (404)

Can someone please help on how I can ensure all 3 apps are running

```
(http://MY_IP:8081/some1_endpoint)
(http://MY_IP:8082/some2_endpoint)
(http://MY_IP:8083/some3_endpoint)
```

If you can point which part(s) among **1-6** can be edited, it would be great
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that gunicorn.sock works (for one of the sites). Was the socket and service configuration restarted after making the original changes and are all of the services running?

```
sudo systemctl restart <name>.socket
sudo systemctl restart <name>.service
sudo systemctl status <name>.service
```

Are these services accessible directly (i.e. when not using nginx as a proxy)? Consider modifying the gunicorn exec and review the error log.

```
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/NTH_project/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --error-logfile /path/to/error.log ...
```

Once services are confirmed as accessible, check the nginx configuration for errors, ensuring that the proxy_params is in the expected location, or remove this line if problematic and enter any required proxy configuration directly.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Once verified, restart nginx to re-establish the socket connection to Gunicorn and validate no further issues.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl status nginx
tail var/log/nginx/error.log
```